# Is rospython subscriber thread safe?

Tags: ros, python

I'm trying to write a python node, which has one class and two member functions as callback functions.
so a TimeSynchronizer and Subscriber in a node.
I saw in this link and tested that python subscribers are event-driven model and are in separate threads.
[How to get a python node in ROS subscribe to multiple topics?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/6652/how-to-get-a-python-node-in-ros-subscribe-to-multiple-topics)

My question here is , are they thread safe when they are working on the same class member? e.g. self.a below. Do I need to write a lock? Where can I find more information about this?
Thank you in advanced!!!!

class mr_listener(object):

```
def __init__(self):
    self.a =  [1,2,3,4,5]
    rospy.init_node('mr_listener', anonymous=True)
    scan_subscriber = message_filters.Subscriber('/scan',LaserScan)
    pose_subscriber = message_filters.Subscriber('/slam_out_pose', PoseStamped)
    ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([scan_subscriber,projected_scan_subscriber,pose_subscriber], 10, 0.1, allow_headerless=True)
    ts.registerCallback(self.callback1)
    rospy.Subscriber("chatter", String, self.callback2)
    rospy.spin()

def callback1(self,scan,pose):
    somthing

def callback2(self,chatt):
    somingthing
    rospy.sleep(1.)
```

Answer (score 3):

> For a particular topic, there is only one thread that all the
>   subscribers share.
>
> Each service callback does get its own thread because there can only
>   be one service callback for a particular service.
>
> Future versions of `rospy` will likely have a different, more
>   versatile threading model for subscriptions.

`rospy.spin()` is a built-in asynchronous method in contrast with `roscpp::spin()` which is single thread (`roscpp::AsyncSpinner()` is async).

> Callbacks in `rospy` in general is they're essentially handled
>   sequentially during calls to `Sleep` and `Spin`, meaning they're
>   implicitly threadsafe and I can modify the same data from multiple
>   callbacks within a node without locks or other safeguards.
>
> Unfortunately, no. Unlike `roscpp`, `rospy` creates a new thread for every
>   `Subscriber` and `Timer`. In fact, `rospy.spin()` is just an infinite loop
>   of half-second waits. As such, callbacks in `rospy` are not threadsafe.
>   You should use `locks` in any `rospy` node where multiple callbacks of any
>   kind might interact.