# Is rospython subscriber thread safe?

Tags: rospy, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey
I'm trying to write a python node, which has one class and two member functions  as callback functions.
**so a TimeSynchronizer and Subscriber in a node.**
I saw in this link and tested that **python subscribers are  event-driven model and are in separate threads**.
[How to get a python node in ROS subscribe to multiple topics?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/6652/how-to-get-a-python-node-in-ros-subscribe-to-multiple-topics)

**My question here is ,**  are they **thread safe** when they are working on the same class member? e.g. self.a below.
Do I need to write a lock? Where can I find more information about this?
Thank you in advanced!!!!

```
class mr_listener(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a =  [1,2,3,4,5]
        rospy.init_node('mr_listener', anonymous=True)
        scan_subscriber = message_filters.Subscriber('/scan',LaserScan)
        pose_subscriber = message_filters.Subscriber('/slam_out_pose', PoseStamped)
        ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([scan_subscriber,projected_scan_subscriber,pose_subscriber], 10, 0.1, allow_headerless=True)
        ts.registerCallback(self.callback1)
        rospy.Subscriber("chatter", String, self.callback2)
        rospy.spin()
    
    def callback1(self,scan,pose):
        somthing

    def callback2(self,chatt):
        somingthing
        rospy.sleep(1.)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313272/is-rospython-subscriber-thread-safe?/) by [jlyw1017](https://answers.ros.org/users/35264/jlyw1017/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@stevemartin 's answer is incorrect.

[roscpp Single Threaded Spinning](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning) is thread safe.

However, your question is on rospy. [rospy subscribers have their own threads](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber). I'm not clear if each subscriber runs on a separate thread, or if all subscribers for a given topic runs on a single thread and subscribers on different topics run on separate threads. Haven't been able to find that in documentation.

Bottom line, you can't assume thread safety in rospy. Use mutual exclusion to access shared resources in callback functions.

---

Originally posted by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) with karma: 849 on 2019-06-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score -1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, ros nodes are threadsafe. You can read more about it here:
[LINK](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview)

---

Originally posted by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) with karma: 361 on 2019-01-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-01-21**:
OP asked about nodes written in Python i.e. using the client library [rospy](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy) not [roscpp](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp), they don't share the same mechanics.

**Comment by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on 2019-01-21**:
@Delb in terms of thread-safeness, they do

Comment: *@Delb in terms of thread-safeness, they do*  This answer is not correct. If a topic has two or more publishers, then a rospy subscribe callback is not thread-safe.